# AWS Batch - passing UserData to Container Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

I am working on aws batch to pass user data during the initialization of the container instance. Is there a way to do it in aws batch ?

Followed this link 
[Create AWS Batch Managed Compute Environment passing UserData to Container Instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987642/create-aws-batch-managed-compute-environment-passing-userdata-to-container-insta/54522401#54522401)

but not sure how they ended up solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an EC2 **Launch Template** and pass the `UserData` script to it. Then use this launch template while creating your AWS Batch `Compute Environment`.

Refer to [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/launch-templates.html) to understand Launch Template support while creating AWS Batch `Compute Environment`.

Cheers,

Kunal

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your user data, I see multiple options to expose data to AWS Batch jobs / containers:

- for key/value pairs, expose the data via environment variables - use the container_overrides parameter for aws batch ( see [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/batch/submit-job.html) or use the aws cli :

`aws batch submit-job --container-overrides vcpus=integer,memory=integer,command=[string,string],environment=[{name=EnvVariableName,value=EnvVariableValue},{name=string,value=string}]`

Or just write your variables to a json file and use `--cli-input-json my_file.json`

- If you have large data, store it in S3, hand over the S3 address during startup and then pull the data during startup ; the aws batch job needs to have permission to fetch data from S3
- for secrets, use the AWS Secret manager to store them, allow your AWS Batch jobs to use  secretsmanager:GetSecretValue and pull the secret from AWS